# Upgrade option is disabled while trying to upgrade to 14.04 using DVD

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 using DVD. When I want to upgrade, upgrade option is disabled. It seems I have to erase 13.10, so all of programs will be deleted.

What's the problem? Why I can't upgarade?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem myself. I should first run the Live version and then upgrade using Ubuntu Live.